# How to get callback error to alert in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cordova, error-handling

I am building app with [PhoneGap](https://phonegap.com/). It working fine on my PC. But when I installed it as android app it did not work. It fire `alert('Oppps...something went wrong')`.

I have following code...

```
function getFloors(url, callback){
    var data = $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "http://example.com/all_test/get_floors.php"
            }).done(callback).error(function(e){
               alert('Oppps...something went wrong')
            });
    return data;
};
```

Let assume there is no page like `http://example.com/all_test/get_floors.php`.

Then you can find error in console like `GET http://example.com/all_test/get_floorss.php 404 (Not Found)`.

I need to display that error as alert. I mean I need to print real error instead of `alert('Oppps...something went wrong')`. So I can find what is issue in mobile.

How should I get that error (what display on the console) for a alert.

Comment: perhaps `e` has what you're looking for? note: you are using a deprecated `.error` method - from the **documentation** `the .fail() method replaces the deprecated .error() method.`

Comment: @JaromandaX You mean `done(callback).error(function(e){
               alert(e)
            });`.... It returns [object Object].

Comment: well, if you look at the **documentation** ... `.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown )` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson if you just print the "object object" in console.log then using developer tools console tab and go through the object you will find the error then you can use that show in alert for ex object[0].error = "This is the real error". Something like this

Comment: @shv22 IT return very large object. Something like `{readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort
:
ƒ (a)
always
:
ƒ ()
complete
:
ƒ ()
done
:
ƒ ()
error
:
ƒ ()
fail
:
ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders
:
ƒ ()
getResponseHeader
:
ƒ (a)
overrideMimeType
:
ƒ (a)
pipe
:
ƒ ()
progress
:
ƒ ()
promise
:
ƒ (a)
readyState
:
0
setRequestHeader
:
ƒ (a,b)
state
:
ƒ ()
status
:
0
statusCode
:
ƒ (a)
statusText
:
"error"
success
:
ƒ ()
then
:
ƒ ()
__proto__
:
Object`.. How find it?

Comment: Did you try alert(e.message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this documentation

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

the `e` on `error(function(e)` returns a jqXHR object which returns following properties that you can print at your disposal

> readyState
>
> responseXML and/or responseText - when the underlying request responded
>   with xml and/or text, respectively
>
> status
>
> statusText

I think you are trying to find the `e.responseText` or `e.responseXML`

Comment: Both e.responseText and e.responseXML are undefined. e.statusText return just  "error".  e.error return something like `function (){if(h){var c=h.length;!function g(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&g(c)})}(arguments),d?f=h.length:b&&(e=c,j(b))}return this}`. Is there anything I can try?

Comment: what does `e.status` or `e.statusText` returns? error 50x? or error 40x?